# Laravel 4: Can I tell which route is calling the controller function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel app with 2 groups of routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@apiLogin']);
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::post('/login', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@adminLogin']);
}
```

In an effort to save time and prevent writing double code I'd like to condense the `apiLogin()` and `adminLogin()` function to one function: `login()`. I'd also like to return different things based on the route that is calling the function.

If the request is coming from `/api/login` I want to return `Response::json($apiResponse)`. If the request is coming `/admin/login` I want to return `Redirect::('route.to.redirect.to')`

Is there a way I can tell where the controller function is being called from? (preferable without parsing the URL)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way of doing this in laravel, but to prevent code duplication I have taken a different approach. Let your API controller handle all login logic and simple call your API login from your direct login controller.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanCrowe I'm gonna go with this approach if there aren't any other answers that promise a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the route in your controller. *(I'm not saying this is the best solution for your problem, but you can)*

The best way to do this is by **naming** your routes. [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes)

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'apiLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@apiLogin']);

Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'adminLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthenticationController@adminLogin']);
```

And then you just do

```
Route::currentRouteName();
```

---

If for some reason you can't name your routes you can still get the path of the route (that's not the full url but the segment that's defined in the route. groups included)

So `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath()` should return either `api/login` or `admin/login`

Answer (score 1):

You can check URL in controller, but the better solution in this case would be probably leaving routes as they are, create login method with parameter:

```
public function login($from) {

}
```

and define `apiLogin` and `adminLogin` functions this way:

```
public function apiLogin() {
   return $this->login('api');
}

public function adminLogin() {
   return $this->login('admin');
}
```

this way, if you will decide in future to change the code you will change the code only of those methods, leaving routes without a change.